# Joining 2 tables with different row amount

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with joining 2 tables with different quantity of rows. I tried `LEFT JOIN`, but it does not work, and I suppose that’s because of the `ID_advertentie`.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID_kenmerk = table2.ID_kenmerk
WHERE table1.categorie = 1 AND table2.ID_advertentie = 17
```

How can I write one query with the outcome mentioned as below the table examples?

```
Table 1
ID_kenmerk      Categorie     Naam_kenmerk    Plaatje_kenmerk    Data_type
1           -       1      -   Kenmerk a   -   plaatje1.gif   -    INT
2           -       1      -   Kenmerk b   -   plaatje2.gif   -    BOOL
3           -       1      -   Kenmerk c   -   Plaatje3.jpg   -    INT
4           -       1      -   Kenmerk d   -   plaatje4.jpg   -    VARCHAR
5           -       2      -   Kenmerk F   -   plaatje1.gif   -    INT
6           -       2      -   Kenmerk G   -   plaartje2.gif  -    VARCHAR

Table 2
ID_kenmerk_data     ID_kenmerk     ID_advertentie      value
1                -      1       -       17         -   Test1
2                -      2       -       17         -   Test2
3                -      3       -       17         -   Test3
4                -      1       -       23         -   lala1
5                -      2       -       23         -   lala2
6                -      3       -       23         -   ajdk2
```

Outcome query (`WHERE ID_advertentie = 17`!)

```
ID_kenmerk    Naam_kenmerk     value
1          -   Kenmerk a   - Test1
2          -   Kenmerk b   - Test2
3          -   Kenmerk c   - Test3
4          -   Kenmerk d   - NULL
```

Comment: for ID_kenmerk 4, the ID_advertentie is not 17...

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID_kenmerk = table2.ID_kenmerk AND table2.ID_advertentie = 17
WHERE table1.categorie = 1
```

Just about anything that you use in the `WHERE` clause can also be used inside the `ON` clause. But moving the `table2.ID_advertentie = 17` from the `WHERE` to the `ON` clause will add a NULLed row on the right hand side if there is no match instead of eliminating it.

(Edit) Alternate method:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID_kenmerk = table2.ID_kenmerk
WHERE table1.categorie = 1 AND (table2.ID_kenmerk_data IS NULL OR table2.ID_advertentie = 17)
```

Answer (score 2):

You were right that you need a `LEFT JOIN`. But when you do a (`LEFT`) `OUTER JOIN`, any `WHERE` condition on the right table cancels the outer join.

Solution is to move the condition regarding (the right) `table2` (the `table2.ID_advertentie = 17` one) from the `WHERE`to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 
  ON  table1.ID_kenmerk = table2.ID_kenmerk
  AND table2.ID_advertentie = 17             --- this condition moved
WHERE table1.categorie = 1
```